# Creating a conda environment with python 3.8 with conflicting requirement(s)?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

### Context

After setting up a conda `environment.yml` and trying to install it with a `python 3.8` version, I am experiencing some difficulties.

### Attempts

I tried explicitly specifying the python version at the environment creation command:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml python=3.8
```

I tried explicitly including the `python` version in the `environment.yml` file:

```
...
dependencies:
- anaconda
- python=3.8
- conda:
# Run python tests.
  - pytest-cov
...
```

And I tried explicitly installing python 3.8 inside the environment with:

```
conda activate env_name
conda install python==3.8
```

Which yields a conflict:

> Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

So I tried determining what the conflict is, by evaluating the 2000 output lines that describe the conflicts. I think the first conflict is most relevant:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (pip):

  - python=3.8 -> pip
```

### Environment

The conda environment consists of the following four files:

1. `environment.yml`
2. `pyproject.toml`
3. `requirements.txt`
4. `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

Which have contents:

environment.yml:

```
# This file is to automatically configure your environment. It allows you to
# run the code with a single command without having to install anything
# (extra).

# First run:: conda env create --file environment.yml
# If you change this file, run: conda env update --file environment.yml

# Instructions for this networkx-to-lava-nc repository only. First time usage
# On Ubuntu (this is needed for lava-nc):
# sudo apt upgrade
# sudo apt full-upgrade
# yes | sudo apt install gcc

# Conda configuration settings. (Specify which modules/packages are installed.)
name: networkx-to-lava
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.8
- conda:
# Run python tests.
  - pytest-cov
# Generate plots.
  - matplotlib
# Run graph software quickly.
  - networkx
- pip
- pip:
# Run pip install on .tar.gz file in GitHub repository (For lava-nc only).
  - https://github.com/lava-nc/lava/releases/download/v0.3.0/lava-nc-0.3.0.tar.gz
# Turns relative import paths into absolute import paths.
  - absolufy-imports
# Auto format Python code to make it flake8 compliant.
  - autoflake
# Scan Python code for security issues.
  - bandit
# Code formatting compliance.
  - black
# Correct code misspellings.
  - codespell
# Verify percentage of code that has at least 1 test.
  - coverage
# Auto formats the Python documentation written in the code.
  - docformatter
# Auto generate docstrings.
  - flake8
# Auto sort the import statements.
  - isort
# Auto format Markdown files.
  - mdformat
# Auto check static typing.
  - mypy
# Auto generate documentation.
  - pdoc3
# Auto check programming style aspects.
  - pylint
# Auto generate docstrings.
  - pyment
# Identify and remove dead code.
  - vulture
# Include GitHub pre-commit hook.
  - pre-commit
# TODO: identify exact function(and usage).
# Seems to be an autoformatter like black, but installed using npm instead of pip.
  - prettier
# Automatically upgrades Python syntax to the new Python version syntax.
  - pyupgrade
# Another static type checker for python like mypy.
  - pyright
```

pyproject.toml:

```
# This is used to configure the black, isort and mypy such that the packages don't conflict.
# This file is read by the pre-commit program.
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.mypy_cache
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''


[tool.coverage.run]
# Due to a strange bug with xml output of coverage.py not writing the full-path
# of the sources, the full root directory is presented as a source alongside
# the main package. As a result any importable Python file/package needs to be
# included in the omit
source = [
    "foo",
    ".",
]
# Excludes the following directories from the coverage report
omit = [
    "tests/*",
    "setup.py",
]


[tool.isort]
profile = "black"


[tool.mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = true


[tool.pylint.basic]
bad-names=[]
[tool.pylint.messages_control]
# Example: Disable error on needing a module-level docstring
disable=[
    "import-error",
    "invalid-name",
    "fixme",
]


[tool.pytest.ini_options]
# Runs coverage.py through use of the pytest-cov plugin
# An xml report is generated and results are output to the terminal
addopts = "--cov --cov-report xml:cov.xml --cov-report term"
# Sets the minimum allowed pytest version
minversion = 5.0
# Sets the path where test files are located (Speeds up Test Discovery)
testpaths = ["tests"]
```

requirements.txt

```
# This file ensures that the pre-commit service is ran every time you commit.
# Basically it ensures people only push files to GIT that are up to standard.
pre-commit
```

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
# This file specifies which checks are performed by the pre-commit service.
# The pre-commit service prevents people from pushing code to git that is not
# up to standards. # The reason mirrors are used instead of the actual
# repositories for e.g. black and flake8, is because those repositories also
# need to contain a pre-commit hook file, which they often don't by default.
# So to resolve that, a mirror is created that includes such a file.

default_language_version:
    python: python3.10  # or python3


repos:
# Test if the python code is formatted according to the Black standard.
 - repo: https://github.com/Quantco/pre-commit-mirrors-black
   rev: 22.3.0
   hooks:
     - id: black-conda
       args:
         - --safe
         - --target-version=py36

# Test if the python code is formatted according to the flake8 standard.
 - repo: https://github.com/Quantco/pre-commit-mirrors-flake8
   rev: 4.0.1
   hooks:
    - id: flake8-conda

# Test if the import statements are sorted correctly.
 - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort
   rev: 5.10.1
   hooks:
    - id: isort
      args: ["--profile", "black", --line-length=79]

# Test if the variable typing is correct. (Variable typing is when you say:
# def is_larger(nr: int) -> bool: instead of def is_larger(nr). It makes
# it explicit what type of input and output a function has.
# - repo: https://github.com/python/mypy
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
# - repo: https://github.com/a-t-0/mypy
   rev: v0.950
   hooks:
    - id: mypy

# Tests if there are spelling errors in the code.
 - repo: https://github.com/codespell-project/codespell
   rev: v2.1.0
   hooks:
    - id: codespell

# Performs static code analysis to check for programming errors.
 - repo: local
   hooks:
     - id: pylint
       name: pylint
       entry: pylint
       language: system
       types: [python]
       args:
         [
           "-rn", # Only display messages
           "-sn", # Don't display the score
         ]

# Runs additional tests that are created by the pre-commit software itself.
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
   rev: v4.2.0
   hooks:
    # Check user did not add large files.
    - id: check-added-large-files
    # Check if `.py` files are written in valid Python syntax.
    - id: check-ast
    # Require literal syntax when initializing empty or zero Python builtin types.
    - id: check-builtin-literals
    # Checks if there are filenames that would conflict if case is changed.
    - id: check-case-conflict
    # Checks if the Python functions have docstrings.
    - id: check-docstring-first
    # Checks if any `.sh` files have a shebang like #!/bin/bash
    - id: check-executables-have-shebangs
    # Verifies json format of any `.json` files in repo.
    - id: check-json
    # Checks if there are any existing merge conflicts caused by the commit.
    - id: check-merge-conflict
    # Checks for symlinks which do not point to anything.
    - id: check-symlinks
    # Checks if xml files are formatted correctly.
    - id: check-xml
    # Checks if .yml files are valid.
    - id: check-yaml
    # Checks if debugger imports are performed.
    - id: debug-statements
    # Detects symlinks changed to regular files with content path symlink was pointing to.
    - id: destroyed-symlinks
    # Checks if you don't accidentally push a private key.
    - id: detect-private-key
    # Replaces double quoted strings with single quoted strings.
    # This is not compatible with Python Black.
    #- id: double-quote-string-fixer
    # Makes sure files end in a newline and only a newline.
    - id: end-of-file-fixer
    # Removes UTF-8 byte order marker.
    - id: fix-byte-order-marker
    # Add <# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-> to the top of python files.
    - id: fix-encoding-pragma
    # Checks if there are different line endings, like \n and crlf.
    - id: mixed-line-ending
    # Asserts `.py` files in folder `/test/` (by default:) end in `_test.py`.
    - id: name-tests-test
      # Override default to check if `.py` files in `/test/` START with `test_`.
      args: ['--django']
    # Ensures JSON files are properly formatted.
    - id: pretty-format-json
    # Sorts entries in requirements.txt and removes incorrect pkg-resources entries.
    - id: requirements-txt-fixer
    # Sorts simple YAML files which consist only of top-level keys.
    - id: sort-simple-yaml
    # Removes trailing whitespaces at end of lines of .. files.
    - id: trailing-whitespace





 - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/autoflake
   rev: v1.4
   hooks:
    - id: autoflake
      args: ["--in-place", "--remove-unused-variables", "--remove-all-unused-imports", "--recursive"]
      name: AutoFlake
      description: "Format with AutoFlake"
      stages: [commit]

 - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit
   rev: 1.7.4
   hooks:
   - id: bandit
     name: Bandit
     stages: [commit]

# Enforces formatting style in Markdown (.md) files.
 - repo: https://github.com/executablebooks/mdformat
   rev: 0.7.14
   hooks:
   - id: mdformat
     additional_dependencies:
     - mdformat-toc
     - mdformat-gfm
     - mdformat-black

 - repo: https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/absolufy-imports
   rev: v0.3.1
   hooks:
   - id: absolufy-imports
     files: '^src/.+\.py$'
     args: ['--never', '--application-directories', 'src']

 - repo: https://github.com/myint/docformatter
   rev: v1.4
   hooks:
   - id: docformatter

 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pygrep-hooks
   rev: v1.9.0
   hooks:
   - id: python-use-type-annotations
   - id: python-check-blanket-noqa
   - id: python-check-blanket-type-ignore

# Updates the syntax of `.py` files to the specified python version.
# It is not compatible with: pre-commit hook: fix-encoding-pragma
# - repo: https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade
#   rev: v2.32.1
#   hooks:
#     - id: pyupgrade
#       args: [--py310-plus]


 - repo: https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint
   rev: v0.11.0
   hooks:
     - id: markdownlint
```

### Package Conflict Output

```
conda install python=3.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                     \  

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (pip):

  - python=3.8 -> pip

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package openjpeg conflicts for:
openjpeg
pillow -> openjpeg[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.0,<2.5.0a0']
matplotlib-base -> pillow[version='>=6.2.0'] -> openjpeg[version='>=2.3.0,<3.0a0|>=2.4.0,<2.5.0a0']

Package ncurses conflicts for:
wheel -> python -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
krb5 -> libedit[version='>=3.1.20210216,<3.2.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
pluggy -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.3,<7.0a0']
...
...

  - tornado -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - unicodedata2 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxau -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xorg-libxdmcp -> libgcc-ng[version='>=9.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - xz -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zlib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - zstd -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.33
```

### Question

How can I determine the conflicting package in this conda environment and/or how can I create the environment using python 3.8?

Comment: Do you actually need the `anaconda` metapackage? The proposed environment would be orders of magnitude simpler to solve without that thing. Also, I've never seen `conda:` syntax in Conda YAMLs before - where did you get that from? And what is the `conda` channel? There's an `anaconda` channel - perhaps that's what you meant?

Comment: @merv Thank you for your questions, I have removed the `anaconda` metapackage. I thought the `conda:` was for packages that were installed using `conda install <packagename>` (instead of `pip install <packagename>`). However, based on that question, I expect that thought to be incorrect. I will look into it.

Comment: Everything is installed through Conda by default, except those under the `pip:` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After specifying the python version as the first dependency, and removing the unneeded elements as suggested by merv, I found a working yaml. I removed `anaconda`, and the `conda` channel. Furthermore, I ensured the `default_version` in the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file was set to:

```
default_language_version:
    python: python3.8.  # or python3
```

I also deleted the `.mypy_cache` folder in the `.git` repository (even though I think this was not required). And I deleted the directory `/home/<username>/.cache/pre-commit` before running `pre-commit run --all-files`. (I thought it was worth mentioning as it is inherent to this `environment.yml`)

I did not have to specify the python version in the environment creation command. Instead, I ran:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml
```

The working `environment.yml` content is:

```
# This file is to automatically configure your environment. It allows you to
# run the code with a single command without having to install anything
# (extra).

# First run: conda env create --file environment.yml
# If you change this file, run: conda env update --file environment.yml

# Instructions for this networkx-to-lava-nc repository only. First time usage
# On Ubuntu (this is needed for lava-nc):
# sudo apt upgrade
# sudo apt full-upgrade
# yes | sudo apt install gcc

# Conda configuration settings. (Specify which modules/packages are installed.)
name: nx2lava
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
# Specify specific python version.
  - python=3.8
# Run python tests.
  - pytest-cov
# Generate plots.
  - matplotlib
# Run graph software quickly.
  - networkx
  - pip
  - pip:
# Run pip install on .tar.gz file in GitHub repository (For lava-nc only).
    - https://github.com/lava-nc/lava/releases/download/v0.3.0/lava-nc-0.3.0.tar.gz
# Turns relative import paths into absolute import paths.
    - absolufy-imports
# Auto format Python code to make it flake8 compliant.
    - autoflake
# Scan Python code for security issues.
    - bandit
# Code formatting compliance.
    - black
# Correct code misspellings.
    - codespell
# Verify percentage of code that has at least 1 test.
    - coverage
# Auto formats the Python documentation written in the code.
    - docformatter
# Auto generate docstrings.
    - flake8
# Auto sort the import statements.
    - isort
# Auto format Markdown files.
    - mdformat
# Auto check static typing.
    - mypy
# Auto generate documentation.
    - pdoc3
# Auto check programming style aspects.
    - pylint
# Auto generate docstrings.
    - pyment
# Identify and remove dead code.
    - vulture
# Include GitHub pre-commit hook.
    - pre-commit
# TODO: identify exact function(and usage).
# Seems to be an autoformatter like black, but installed using npm instead of pip.
    - prettier
# Automatically upgrades Python syntax to the new Python version syntax.
    - pyupgrade
# Another static type checker for python like mypy.
    - pyright
```

Which returns the following to the `python --version` command:

> Python 3.8.13